# Error with adding two textbox values into third one C#

Tags: c#, textbox

I am trying to insert `textbox1 + textbox2 = textbox3`. And all my textboxes are set to `selectAll();` while entering into textbox. So when I entered to `textbox1` all the text will be in select mode and if I click backspace all data will be removed and an error occurring like

> *Input string was not in correct format*

My code is

```
textBox3.Text = (int.Parse(textBox1.Text) + int.Parse(textBox2.Text)).ToString();`
```

I tried like

```
       if (textBox1.Text != "")
        {
            textBox3.Text = (int.Parse(textBox1.Text) + int.Parse(textBox2.Text)).ToString();
        }
```

In this case The value in the Textbox three is not changing when I click backspace. Means textbox will be null. That's why value is not changing in thired textbox. Please help me. How could I ovecome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming that your inputs (`textBox1.Text` and `textBox2.Text`) are integers.

If they are not, `int.Parse` will fail and give you the error you are seeing.

You need to use `int.TryParse`:

```
int result1 = 0:
int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out result1);
int result2 = 0:
int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out result2);

textBox3.Text = (result1 + result2).ToString():
```

Answer (score 0):

Int is not a nullable item - and since you are tyring to parse a null value (after your back space) it is casuing the error.

use instead int.TryParase(value_to_parse ,out where to store resulting Int)
TryParse returns a boolean to state if parsing was sucessfull
Regards